# A better way of combining data from multiple RxJS observables

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I have the following in my ngOnInit():

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const exerciseObs = this.wodService.getAllExercises().pipe(take(1), map(data => {
      return {exercises: data};
    }));
    const userObs = this.accountService.getAccountInformationObservable().pipe(take(1), map(data => {
      return {user: data};
    }));

    forkJoin([exerciseObs, userObs]).subscribe(data => {
      this.exercises = data[0].exercises as unknown as Exercise[];
      this.user = data[1].user as unknown as CWUser;
    });
  }
```

Combining the output of two observables and then assigning the data to two component properties. How I have to convert to unknown and then the type feels off but I can't workout another way to combine them without resorting to a `switchMap` and combining the data in there. This feels like the cleaner, flatter approach but the data coming back as an array and their weird casting feels off.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hmm.. There is no need to convert it to unknown as long as you provide the types in `exerciseObs` and `userObs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean this up a bit, and keep it typesafe - no need for the gymnastics you are doing with `data` if you use deconstruct the tuple returned by `forkJoin`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const exerciseObs = this.wodService.getAllExercises().pipe(take(1));
  const userObs = this.accountService.getAccountInformationObservable().pipe(take(1));

  forkJoin([exerciseObs, userObs]).subscribe({
    next: ([exercises, user]) => {
      this.exercises = exercises;
      this.user = user; 
    }
  });
}
```

[Stackblitz for this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-answer-61654111?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts). Check `hello.component.ts`.

Comment: Yes! This is what my brain was reaching for when it was saying "I just want to grab each array element by name but how?!" Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you provide the types when you declare both of the above constants, there will be no need to carry out any explicit type assertion when you subscribe to the `forkjoin` of both observables.

```
const exerciseObs: Observable<Exercise[]> = this.wodService.getAllExercises()
  .pipe(
    take(1), 
    map(data => ({
      exercises: data,
    }))
);
const userObs: Observable<userObs>  = this.accountService.getAccountInformationObservable()
  .pipe(
    take(1), 
    map(data => ({
      user: data,
    }))
);
```

Comment: Thanks, had to modify to const exerciseObs: Observable<{exercises: Exercise[]}> = to make tslint happy but that allowed me to remove the unknown